# Выбивает ошибку cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**'

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int zamena( int **A , int N, int M, int min , int max )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
            if( A[i][j] < max ) {
                A[i][j] = min;
            }
            cout << A[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL , "Russian" );
    int N, M, max, min;

    cout << "input N ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "input M ";
    cin >> M;

    int Arr[N][M];

    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
            cout << "Введите значение " << i << j <<
                 " элемента массива: ";
            cin >> Arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    max = Arr[0][0];
    min = Arr[0][0];

    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
            if( Arr[i][j] > max ) {
                max = Arr[i][j];
            }

            if( Arr[i][j] < min ) {
                min = Arr[i][j];
            }
            zamena( &Arr[0][0], N, M, min, max );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

У функции `zamena` первый параметр объявлен, как имеющий тип `int **`

```
int zamena(int** A , int N, int M, int min , int max){ 
           ^^^^^^^
```

Вы вызываете эту функцию с аргументом, имеющим тип `int *`

```
 zamena(&Arr[0][0], N, M, min, max);
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

так как тип элемента массива `Arr[0][0]`  имеет тип `int`, а указатель на этот эдемент массива `&Arr[0][0]` имеет тип `int *`.

Не существует неявного преобразования из типа `int *` в тип `int **`, да и в данном случае это бессмысленно.

Так как вы используете массивы переменной длины, которые, кстати сказать, не поддерживаются стандартом C++, то попробуйте объявить функцию следующим образом

```
int zamena( int N, int M, int ( *A )[M] , int min , int max){
```

и вызывайте ее как

```
 zamena( N, M, Arr, min, max);
```

Было бы проще и соответствовало бы стандарту C++ использовать стандартный контейнер `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` вместо массива переменной длины.